# jQuery When function activate make another function available

Tags: jquery

I would like to show `<p>` in `#info` by clicking `h1` and after showing it I would like to hide it again with one more click on `h1`. Thanks for help!

**HTML**

```
<article id="info">
    <h1>Lerem ipsum<i class="icon-up-open-big"><!--arrow!--></i></h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse consectetur
        ligula vel nunc ultricies, nec iaculis libero bibendum. Vestibulum eu lorem
        faucibus, eleifend justo non, bibendum leo. Cras in nulla pharetra, tristique
        felis et, vulputate mauris. Ut vitae nunc in massa rhoncus tempus fringilla
        congue sem. Sed est eros, maximusn eget turpis ut, porttitor vehicula metus. Fusce
        neque turpis, venenatis eu auctor non, malesuada at sapien. Phasellus orci arcu,
        bibendum eu ultrices non, blandit quis enim. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
        ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed feugiat augue vitae leo accumsan, vitae tempor velit
        interdum.
</article>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var open = 0;

jQuery(function($) {
    if(open == 0) {
        $('#info').click(function() {
            $(this).css('cursor', 'default');
            $('#info h1').css('cursor', 'pointer');
            $('#info p').slideDown(1000);
            $('#info i').animate({rotate: '180'}, 2000, 'linear', function() {rotate();});
            var open = 1;
        });
    }
    else if (open == 1) {
        $('#info h1').click(function() {
            $('#info p').slideUp(1000);
            var open = 0;
        });
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
#info {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 110px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    font-size: 50px;
    width: 75vw;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#info h1 {
    font-size: 175%;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

#info p  {
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 85%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', 'h1', function(){
  $('p').toggle();
})
```

Here are some animations you can use with the toggle method: [docs](https://jqueryui.com/toggle/)
Or you can use the [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use toogleClass method, if you want a transition you can use more css.

```js
$("#info").on('click', function(){
     $("#info p").toggleClass( "hide" )
 })
```

```css
{
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 110px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    font-size: 50px;
    width: 75vw;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#info h1
{
    font-size: 175%;
    text-decoration: none ;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin:0;
}

#info p 
{
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 85%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.show{
  display:block
}

.hide{
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="info">
            <h1>Lerem ipsum<i class="icon-up-open-big"><!--arrow!--></i></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse consectetur ligula vel nunc ultricies, nec iaculis libero bibendum. Vestibulum eu lorem faucibus, eleifend justo non, bibendum leo. Cras in nulla pharetra, tristique felis et, vulputate mauris. Ut vitae nunc in massa rhoncus tempus fringilla congue sem. Sed est eros, maximus eget turpis ut, porttitor vehicula metus. Fusce neque turpis, venenatis eu auctor non, malesuada at sapien. Phasellus orci arcu, bibendum eu ultrices non, blandit quis enim. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed feugiat augue vitae leo accumsan, vitae tempor velit interdum.
        </article>
```

Comment: I would like this animation to stay